# Django REST framework - sumbit only fields?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I use a model serializer in my code and need to get extra field value in the PUT request. This is to identify the user intention on certain operations. I see there are `read_only` and `write_only` option in serialize fields. But I can't use those since I'm not going to store this additional field to the model (it don't have such field).

How can I achieve this in the serializer correct way?

```
djangorestframework version 3.13.1
```

Comment: Just add them to your `Serializer` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution based on the @loki's comment.

Included the serializer field as follows since I use it for PUT method only.

```
delete_now = serializers.BooleanField(default=False, write_only=True)
```